# perform pivot action on sql table containing datetime

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am trying to do a pivot on my sql table which are displayed below. My goal is for every distinct date, i have the Title corresponding to it. Each date could have multiple titles. However I do not want to average the titles so no aggregation is occuring. How do I achieve this. 
[image]

The Title are referencing Jobs, so for each Date I need to see what were the JObs that were performed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this modification to your query:

```
select distinct 
  CAST(day AS date) AS day, 
  title
from ee
order by day, title
```